# Can a .Net application support both the AspCompat directive and WebSockets (used by SignalR) at the same time?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, comobject

I'm working on calling a COM object from a web form inside a web application running on the .Net 4.5.2 framework.  I recieve the following error message when using the AspCompat="true" page directive, which is required to call a STA (single-threaded apartment) COM object:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: <%@ Page AspCompat="true" %> and <httpRuntime apartmentThreading="true" /> are unsupported in the current application configuration. To work around this, add the following configuration switch in Web.config:
<appSettings>
 <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />
</appSettings>
For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252465.
```

The error message states I need to include **aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext = false** in the app settings in the web.config file.  This resolves the first exception, but causes a new exception to be thrown, requesting the app setting be removed, since the application also uses WebSockets (used by SignalR):

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: WebSockets is unsupported in the current application configuration. To work around this, remove the following configuration switch in Web.config:
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" />
</appSettings>
For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252465.
   at System.Web.Util.SynchronizationContextUtil.ValidateMode(SynchronizationContextMode currentMode, SynchronizationContextMode requiredMode, String specificErrorMessage)
   at System.Web.HttpContext.AcceptWebSocketRequest(Func`2 userFunc, AspNetWebSocketOptions options)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport.AcceptWebSocketRequest(Func`2 callback)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequestPostGroupRead(HostContext context, String groupsToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.TaskAsyncHelper.FromMethod[T1,T2,T3,TResult](Func`4 func, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
```

Is it possible to include the AspCompat="true" page directive in a web form and still use WebSockets (used by SignalR) elsewhere in the .Net application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. SignalR is just a client-side JavaScript library plus an handler on the server-side (not the same ASP.NET page).
WebSockets, on the other side, are only supported in Windows 8 or higher and a Windows feature must be installed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Just to clarify the question, I'm trying to determine if WebSockets (used by Signal R) and the AspCompat="true" page directive can be used in the same application since Asp.Net requires the aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext app setting to exist for one but be removed for the other.

Comment: Yes, they can. Nothing to do with that.